# Issue notification via Geofencing

Tags: android

I want my app to issue notification when user enters in the geofencing area.
Neither it issues notification nor it shows Circle at map that i have defined for getting geofence coloured view. what's wrong ? kindly cooperate with me , this thing took a long long time from me. I will be thankful to ur cooperation.

Main file,

```
 public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{

protected GoogleMap gMap;
private LocationManager locationManager;

    double clat,clong;
    List<Geofence> mGeofenceList;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    gMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    if (gMap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Google Maps not available",           
         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}

      locate();
      geofencing();

    gMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);         

        Intent intent = new Intent(this,TransitionsIntentService.class);
        startService(intent);
}   


     private void geofencing() {

     // Instantiate the current List of geofences
           mGeofenceList = new ArrayList<Geofence>();
           Geofence geofence1 = new Geofence.Builder()
    .setRequestId("your target place")
    .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
    .setCircularRegion(clat,clong, 2000.0f)
    .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)
    .build();

           mGeofenceList.add(geofence1);
           CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions()
     .center( new LatLng(clat,clong) )
     .radius(20000)
     .fillColor(Color.BLUE)
     .strokeColor(Color.BLUE);

           // Get back the mutable Circle
            gMap.addCircle(circleOptions);

    }

        private void locate() {


    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

            clat=location.getLatitude();
            clong=location.getLongitude();

        }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
      };

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 10000, 10, locationListener);              

    }

  }
```

TransitionsIntentService.java file,

```
 public class TransitionsIntentService extends IntentService {
     public static final String TRANSITION_INTENT_SERVICE = "ReceiveTransitionsIntentService";
   private List<Geofence> mGeofenceList;
    public TransitionsIntentService() {
       super(TRANSITION_INTENT_SERVICE);
   }
    @Override
      protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
          // First check for errors
        if (LocationClient.hasError(intent)) {
         // Get the error code with a static method
        int errorCode = LocationClient.getErrorCode(intent);
        // Log the error
        Log.e("ReceiveTransitionsIntentService",
                "Location Services error: " +
                Integer.toString(errorCode));
        /*
         * You can also send the error code to an Activity or
         * Fragment with a broadcast Intent
         */
       /*
        * If there's no error, get the transition type and the IDs
        * of the geofence or geofences that triggered the transition
        */
       } else {
        // Get the type of transition (entry or exit)
        int transitionType =
                LocationClient.getGeofenceTransition(intent);
        // Test that a valid transition was reported
        if (
            (transitionType == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER)
             ||
            (transitionType == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
           ) {
            List <Geofence> triggerList =
                    getTriggeringGeofences(intent);


            String[] triggerIds = new String[mGeofenceList.size()];

            for (int i = 0; i < triggerIds.length; i++) {
                // Store the Id of each geofence
                triggerIds[i] = triggerList.get(i).getRequestId();
            }
            /*
             * At this point, you can store the IDs for further use
             * display them, or display the details associated with
             * them.
             */
        }
       // An invalid transition was reported
        else {
          Log.e("ReceiveTransitionsIntentService",
                "Geofence transition error: ");

          }
       }
    }



  private List<Geofence> getTriggeringGeofences(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     notification();
    return null;
  }



         @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
         private void notification()
    {
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.jollyr)
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
        .setContentTitle("Flood Warning")
        .setContentText("You are in Danger Zone");


    Intent i= new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);

    /* The stack builder object will contain an artificial back stack for the
    started Activity.
    This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of
    your application to the Home screen.*/
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
   stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
   // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
   stackBuilder.addNextIntent(i);
   PendingIntent pi =
        stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
            0,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        );
   mBuilder.setContentIntent(pi);
   // Sets an ID for the notification
        int nId = 001;
   // Gets an instance of the NotificationManager service
        NotificationManager mNotifyMgr = 
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // Builds the notification and issues it.   
        mNotifyMgr.notify(nId, mBuilder.build());


       }
   }
```

Manifest File,

```
    <application
       android:allowBackup="true"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.map.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>

        <service android:name=".TransitionsIntentService" />

         <meta-data
          android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
          android:value="AIzaSyBeJoGKnhxYps-youI1xfMZn6S2G05l0PM" />

   </application>
```

Comment: Hey someone there ? kindly cooperate !

Answer (score 1):

your manifest is missing

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your manifest is missing

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

or

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Fine is the one you want also basing the location off of the network may not be accurate enough.